# AJAX:How to pass a single parameter either by serialize the form or send a single parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form for a single field on my page, I just want to know either it is better to send a single parameter like

```
var myObject = {myParameter:'My Value'};
```

OR

```
var myObject = {myParameter : myForm.Serialize()};
```

Comment: first option is better and for the second option you don't need to take parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the service/controller is expecting to receive.  If the parameter is a `form` use `.serialize()` else just specify the value directly.

Behind the scenes `.serialize()` creates a text based string based upon the form elements. I.e.:

```
formItem=FormItem1&FormItem2=formItem2
```

So it really makes no difference.

Comment: Okey Thanks for reply you both guys @Darren Davies And Mac, i need better Practice to do the same from both of the option.